# How to set DataChangePolicy Azure search sdk 3.0.3

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-sql-database, azure-search-.net-sdk

I have enabled change policy my db

```
ALTER Database EMR
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON  
(CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON)  

ALTER TABLE EMR.dbo.ICDCodePCS  
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING  
WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = OFF)
```

and on azure index side i use below for Datasource.AzureSql

```
 DataChangePolicy = new SqlIntegratedChangeTrackingPolicy()
```

when i insert a new row to this table it does not seem to update the index automatically in azure search side. i have to pretty much run the index job after i add new row. how do i trace or debug what am i doing wrong?

i am using azure sql and azure search with sdk 3.0.3

```
var dataIndexer = new AzureDataIndexer()
            {
                DataSource = $"{EMRConsts.EMRAzureIndexNameICD10PCS}-datasource",
                Description = "ICD10 Procedueral Code",
                IndexName = EMRConsts.EMRAzureIndexNameICD10PCS,
                Indexer = $"{EMRConsts.EMRAzureIndexNameICD10PCS}-indexer",
                TableName = EMRConsts.EMRAzureIndexNameICD10PCS,
                DataChangePolicy = new SqlIntegratedChangeTrackingPolicy(),
                Settings = new AzureDataIndexerSettings()
                {
                    ServiceName = _settingManager.GetSettingValue(EMRSettingNames.EmrSearchServiceName),
                    ApiKey = _settingManager.GetSettingValue(EMRSettingNames.EmrSearchServiceApiKeyAdmin)
                },
                Definition = new Index()
                {
                    Name = EMRConsts.EMRAzureIndexNameICD10PCS,
                    Fields = new[]
                    {
                        new Field("ICDCodePCSId", DataType.String)
                        {
                            IsKey = true,
                            IsSearchable = true,
                            IsFilterable = true,
                            IsSortable = true,
                            IsFacetable = false,
                            IsRetrievable = true
                        },
                        new Field("ICDCodePCSName", DataType.String)
                        {
                            IsKey = false,
                            IsSearchable = true,
                            IsFilterable = true,
                            IsSortable = false,
                            IsFacetable = false,
                            IsRetrievable = true
                        },
                        new Field("ICDCodePCSShortName", DataType.String)
                        {
                            IsKey = false,
                            IsSearchable = true,
                            IsFilterable = true,
                            IsSortable = false,
                            IsFacetable = false,
                            IsRetrievable = true
                        }
                    },
                    Suggesters = new[]
                    {
                        new Suggester()
                        {
                            Name = SuggesterName,
                            SearchMode = SuggesterSearchMode.AnalyzingInfixMatching,
                            SourceFields = new List<string>() {"ICDCodePCSName", "ICDCodePCSId", "ICDCodePCSShortName" }
                        },
                    }
```

DataSource

```
    var dataSource =
        DataSource.AzureSql(
            name: dataIndexer.DataSource,
            sqlConnectionString: _appConfigSqlConnection.GetConnection().ConnectionString,
            tableOrViewName: dataIndexer.TableName,
           changeDetectionPolicy: dataIndexer.DataChangePolicy,
            description: dataIndexer.Description);

    try
    {
            _searchClient.Indexes.Create(dataIndexer.Definition);
   var indexer =
            new Indexer()
            {
                Name = dataIndexer.Indexer,
                Description = dataIndexer.Description,
                DataSourceName = dataSource.Name,
                TargetIndexName = dataIndexer.IndexName
            };

            _searchClient.Indexers.Create(indexer);
        _searchClient.DataSources.Create(dataSource);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share your Indexer configuration?

Comment: Check that your indexer has a schedule configured. Without a schedule, the indexer only runs when you explicitly run it.

Comment: @EugeneShvets-MSFT i thought if you use a datachangePolicy with azure SQL change tracking for the table indexed it automatically updated the index without any recurring schedule.

Comment: @Justin Homes Change detection policies are about determining *what* to index, not *when* to index. The schedule determines when (or you can run the indexer explicitly).

Comment: @BruceJohnston so i am reading this incorrectly ?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers#capturing-new-changed-and-deleted-rows

Comment: Please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers#run-indexers-on-a-schedule.

Comment: Also, you need to create the datasource before you create indexer - otherwise, creating the indexer will fail.

Comment: yes i do that, i just copy pasted section of different parts of code above.

Comment: if i understand this correct, change policy is only to make the re-index faster? because what  field to index has already been defined when i initially create the index